# Auto Ban fails?

Tags: support

All answers below was basically the same question, and user who posted was calling us lazy, and worse. Yet he wasn't prevented from posting for a quite long time - he only needed to switch usernames.

I think he exploited some kind of bug in the auto-ban - usually banned users are recognized not only per username, but also per IP and other means. Somehow, he wasn't.

Any chance this will be prevented in future? Or is it something we have to live with?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That user used different IP addresses and user names for every account...not much we can do about that unfortunately :)

People like that don't come along very often, I'm pretty sure he's already got bored. Mods can nuke an account and all its content with literally a couple of clicks, so he was always fighting a losing battle.

Certainly if continues we'll take it to the SE team, but for now I think we're ok.

As a side note, yours and others' flagging was *really* useful with this. When he moved on to spamming answers instead of questions I might have missed it if not for the flags. So muchas gracias

Comment: Well, with some operators it's easy to get brand new IP, and I even wrote a script to do that for me automagically when one public institution (unlawfully) restricted number of reads by IP. I could've guessed it is something like this here. Well, glad we helped. And it appears that there were 2 more people flagging (at least down voting), so even without me you probably wouldn't miss much.

Comment: Yeah, could also have been someone with a feed from http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list/ and automating switching proxies. Quite a few ways to auto-change your IP these days :)